# React container not binding correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a search bar and the value of the input is not displaying in the search bar. When I log the value in the console it only displays one character at a time

[image]

I'm assuming that the way that I have set up my state and term is incorrect and rewriting the state everytime it fires, rather than updating it?

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `=` sign in your `setState` function.

`this.setState` is a function, not a variable. You have to pass argument into it, not assign a new value.

Change it into:

`this.setState({ term: event.target.value })`